# jenkins groovy file steps management : make steps continue on previous errors

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-multibranch

hello I uses a jenkins groovy file to manage steps of my pipeline.

**structure is just like :**

````
>     ```
>     
>     2 pipeline                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      3 {                                                                   
> 4     agent none                                                      
> 5                                                                     
> 6     options {                                                       
> 7         timeout(time: 240, unit: 'MINUTES')                         
> 8     }                                                               
> 9                                                                     
> 10     stages {                                                       
> 11         stage ("clean xxxxxxx") {                                  
> 12             agent {                                                
> 13                 node {                                             
> 14                     label "xxxxxxx"                                
> 15                     customWorkspace "F:\\xxxxxxx"                  
> 16                 }                                                  
> 17             }                                                      
> 18             steps                                                  
> 19             {                                                      
> 20                 script                                             
> 21                 {                                                  
> 22                     bat """                                        
> 23                         f:                                         
> 24                         cd \\                                      
> 25                         python
> xxxxxxx/scripts/pipeline/removeOldJenkinsBuildDir.py --nbdays 30
> --delete yes                                                                                                                        26                         python
> xxxxxxx/scripts/pipeline/cleanDotConan.py f: --delete                 
> 27                         Powershell("Get-wmiObject -Class
> win32_logicaldisk")                                                   
> 28                     """                                            
> 29                 }                                                  
> 30             }                                                      
> 31         }   
>     
>     ```
````

and so on for each nodes of my list.

**my issue**

if one step fails all of the rest starts and ignore message :
`Stage "clean XXXXXXXX" skipped due to earlier failure(s)`.

so steps are skipped but I really want them to run.

**my goal**

set something in here maybe in steps or higher level, to avoid that skip and force all steps to be run.
what can I do for that  ?
change options sets ? add options to each step ?

*(in fact I found many exemples ; but was unable to use them or crashed :) )*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [addressed in the official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure), which provides two suggestions: the Pipeline step `catchError { }` and the native Groovy `try`-`catch`-`finally` syntax for handling exceptions.

Since it sounds like you may want your code to repeat on many different nodes, another option may be to put your nodes into [`parallel` blocks](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure).  A failure in one parallel branch will not halt execution in any of the other parallel branches.

Answer (score 1):

When a Jenkins stage fails, all of the rest starts and ignore message. So stages are skipped but you really want them to run. You can use the catchError block to catch errors and continue with the pipeline. Here’s an example:

```
stage('Example') {
    steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh './run-my-script.sh'
        }
    }
}
```